# How psutil.cpu_percent() function works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu-usage, psutil

I was executing the below two statements in python interpreter.

```
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None, percpu=False)
2.0
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=None, percpu=True)
[1.5, 1.6, 3.7, 3.5]
```

when percpu=False it is expected to give system-wide CPU usage. However, when I try to get each CPU usage, its sum doesn't equal system-wide usage.My question is how exactly cpu_percent function works when percpu=True and percpu=False
is passed?

Answer (score 4):

There are two reasons you do not get what you expect to.

First of all, the value returned with `percpu=False` should be an average, not a sum of the values returned with `percpu=True`. In other words, a call with `percpu=False` returns an average utilization for all cores/CPUs. This makes sense, because if you have 4 cores, and one of them is 100% busy, but three others are idle (0% utilization) then only 25% of total CPU capacity is used.

Second problem is when you pass `interval=None` you get utilization measured since the last call to `cpu_percent`. Quote from [the doc](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.cpu_percent):

> When interval is 0.0 or None compares system CPU times elapsed since last call or module import, returning immediately.

So you are actually compare *different* measures, and obviously CPU utilization might change between these measures.

Comment: do they mention in the docs that percpu=False return average?

Comment: Unfortunately they do not

Comment: What is the recommended interval time?

Answer (score 1):

From my experiments and reading the code it looks like with `psutil.cpu_percent` and `percpu=False`, 100% means that all cores are used 100%. The code comments describe this as the "Windows Task Manager style". This is roughly equivalent to taking the average CPU utilization per core. Instead you might be used to the unix style, which just sums the per-core utilization, so the maximum would be e.g. 400% for your 4-core machine.

Interestingly, `psuitl.Process.cpu_percent` calculates the unix-style utilization instead.

Comment: Yeah. But if we add [1.5, 1.6, 3.7, 3.5]  is not equal to the output for percpu=False, right?

Comment: yes, that's what I said. You can think of `percpu=False` as the average, not the sum